# Changing dates into numeric form to do a correlation

Tags: r, date

i'm trying to make a correlation in R with data that i've imported from a server running mysql.(i'm using rmysql) the problem is that the dates i get aren't numeric and i haven't found out how to change it.

```
'data.frame':   100000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ average : num  18998 18998 18998 18998 18998 ...
 $ date    : chr  "2012-10-01 00:00:00" "2012-10-01 00:00:00" "2012-10-01 00:00:00" "2012-10-01 00:00:00" ...
```

i need to somehow get the date in a form that i can handle with R.

Comment: You can look at the package as.Date for a start : as.Date( "2012-10-01 00:00:00")

Comment: If the dates are not numeric, what are they?

Comment: They were pretty clearly "character".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse the dates, e.g. use

```
yourDF$time <- as.POSIXct(yourDF$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

or whatever the appropriate time format and time zone is for your data. Study `?strptime` for other `format` options.

If you need a numeric time you can use `as.numeric` on the POSIXct vector, i.e., `as.numeric(yourDF$time)`. This will give you seconds since the beginning of 1970.